# Visual Studio 2019 breaks on already handled exception (C#)

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2019

I have some code in a try-catch block, which may throw exceptions.

The exception is handled in the catch block.

The code works under VS 2017. However, switched to VS2019, the debugger won't continue (see screenshot)

**How can I tell the debugger no to break at already handled exceptions ?**

[image]

[Edit]

In this particular case, the exception can easily be **avoided** with more careful code, or disabled by unchecking the **"Break when this exception type is thrown"**.

However it is NOT my question.

My question is :

**Why VS 2019 breaks at alrady handled exceptions ?**

**How can I tell it no to do so ?**

Comment: Write a comment instead of leaving a dislike, would be more appreciated

Comment: Just remove the "Break when exception type is thrown". Or disable "NullReferenceException" in the exception settings.

However, I would not recommend to do this. You should never catch such general exceptions, you should better handle a NULL check.

Comment: Thx for the comment. However it is not what I am asking. I wanted to know why VS 2019 decides to break at un handled exception, and how can I tell it not to do so.

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT: This question is not regarding correct handling, but breaking behaviours. The example contained is of course NOT recommended handling]

As per Mattias Larsson's answer, a number of Exceptions, by default, will always break execution regardless of if they are handled or not. A `System.NullReferenceException` is one of them. To prevent this, you can uncheck the box `break when this exception type is thrown`. Doing so will result in the following behavior:

[image: breaking behaviour]

As you previously commented, when not handled, you wish the debugger to continue to break on a `System.NullReferenceException`; this is the standard behavior since such an exception is critical i.e. not recoverable (perhaps there's a better term?).

Comment: you want to stop breaking at any kind of nullreference exception throughout your application? thats a recipe for errors if you ask me.

Comment: also this is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907337/4122889 and adds no new information

Comment: i downvoted because the answer a) should include the implications of 'checking that box' - meaning that ALL exceptions are ignored, which could be 'dangerous' as in furiously annoying, and b) because it did not add any new information i did not read or could gather from the other answer - which is a requirement for all new answers (that they include new information). Also - don't take this so personally - i gave a downvote and took the time to include my critique for you (and not for myself) so telling me to 'read' is hostility i don't think i deserve. lets keep it friendly :)

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Thanks for taking time to analyse my question. However, the same code does not throw any exception in VS 2017. I suppose it to be a new "feature" in VS 2019

Comment: Based on this example I want to come with the following conclusion : starting from VS 2019, the compiler forces users to avoid null reference exceptions with better logic, instead of handling them with exceptions.

Comment: @DSB Review the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019, it seems the behavior is the same between 2017/19, however note the debugger setting Just My Code and it's implications in this document. It may be that between your installations of VS 2017 and 2019 you have this set differently.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I just made sure the JMC settings are the same for both VS 2017 and 2019. However the debugger behavior difference over my code remains the same.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Also I found this issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/566964/exceptions-caught-and-handled-by-extensions-are-st.html, someone reported a similar (not exactly the same) issue and it seems to be solved back in summer 2019.

Comment: @DSB, I'm afraid that's the extent of my knowledge, I can't say why there's a difference. Perhaps review the link I provided in details, there are a lot of options and customization around these behaviors. I understand you are looking for a general solution and not a case by case "uncheck the checkbox" so I'm sorry not to help.

Comment: @sommmen, Excuse my frustration, continuing on your points a) I am clarifying here against your exact concern. Unchecking the box WILL NOT "stop breaking at any kind of nullreference exception", that is demonstrated in image, it will only stop breaking on unhandled exceptions of that type. See how it breaks on line 25 despite the box being unchecked? Feel free to test it yourself. b) What was added was clarity around point a). I wanted to demonstrate what effect the checkbox had.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of exceptions that (by default) breaks the execution even if you have a 'catch all'. `System.NullReferenceException` is one of them.

However, as you can see in the popup in your screenshot you have the option to turn this specific exception "off". It's currently checked: "**Break when this exception type is thrown**".

Uncheck this box and try again!

(You can adjust the exception settings further in this menu option: Debug / Windows / Exception Settings.)

Comment: I can see this option. However I do want VS to break at this type of exception, as long as it is unhandled

Comment: As far as I know, if you do not catch the exception the debugger should stop even if you have this box unchecked.

Comment: In exception settings it seems to only have exception types. I am unable to find something like "break on handled exception"

Comment: @MattiasLarsson Do you mean I should catch explicitly "System.NullReferenceException", instead of general "Exception" is I do here ? (the same code still works as is in VS2017)

Comment: @DSB, I'd recommend perhaps that you weren't relying on try-catch for something as fundamental as null exceptions. Perhaps your method could evaluate for null arguments with standard conditional logic?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I already solved the particular issue with standard conditional logic. However it is not what I am asking :  Why VS 2019 decides to break at unhandled exception, and how can I tell it not to do so.

Comment: Okay, so to my understanding, as @Mattias Larsson mentioned, if you uncheck the box "break when this exception type is thrown": The debugger will not break in your scenario since you are handling the exception, however, in the case that it is not handled, the debugger will still break since it cannot recover from a null reference.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood As you can see from the screenshot, the exception is handled (although badly). But VS still breaks at it. Same when I handle explicitly System.NullReferenceException. It always breaks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214238/discussion-between-george-kerwood-and-dsb).

Answer (score 0):

There's already a lot being said on why this would be 'bad practice'.

That being said, there is `debuggerStepThrough`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Make sure to read the docs to understand the implications - for ex. that you need JMC to be enabled.

Also when making these dirty exception checks that you do - please make them as specific as possible, to avoid suprises;

```
try
{
   var x = MyFunc();

   // We do a check here that will throw an exception 
   var y = ThisFuncWillThrowNullRef(x);
}
catch(exception)
{
    // ALL exceptions are swallowed
    // What if MyFunc() throws an exception instead of the second function? what do we do then?
}
```

edit; in the app i work on, even if we 'swallow' exceptions like you're doing now, we explicitly and verbosely log the the exception. Always. Exceptions are easier to fix than not knowing what's going on and as your app gets larger there will be more and more happening under the hood.

Comment: OP has explained that is not a question regarding correct exception handling, but the behavior of VS breaking.

Comment: Question was clearly stated as: "Why VS 2019 breaks at already handled exceptions? How can I tell it no to do so?" This answer makes no reference to either point.